# Chrome Bug : Some CSS rules ignored

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I wish I could share some sandbox (jsfiddle) but the css has to be loaded externally for the bug to happen.

You can recreate it very easily, but **it HAS to be remote and with an external stylesheet**. Like often when in PROD.

HTML :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='foo'>Foo</div>
    <div class='bar'>Bar</div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.foo {
    display: inline;
}
.bar {
    float: right;
}
```

With this code you should have this :

[image]

↑ `Foo` and `Bar` **are** on the same line.

But in Chrome, sometimes, what you get is :
[image]

↑ `bar` is not on the same line.

It doen't happen every time so you may have to reload (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) many times to see it happen only *some* times.

But there is ways to **make it happen every time** (or almost). I found at least :

1. When you have the Chrome Inspector opened, to the `elements` tab (it doesn't happen on any tab !)
2. When you have an `iframe` in the page

Thus if you add an iframe such as :

```
<div class='foo'>Foo</div>
<div class='bar'>Bar</div>
<br>
<iframe src="https://www.cia.gov/"></iframe>
```

You will get the bug quite often.

Note that it doesn't happen when the css is internally included with `<style></style>` for example.

The common factor I found between : remote server + external css + iframe + inspector, is that all of these make the page longer to calculate.

Do you have any ideas on why this happens and how to prevent this?

**EDIT :**

**I don't want *another way* for aligning two elements. What I want is understand why.**

I made this quick GIF showing that if you remove the float right, from the inspector and then back again, the bug is resolved, `Bar` gets where it should have be in the first place.

[image]

Comment: Why one is floated and other is inline? Why not `float: left`/`float: right`?

Comment: Put the float first.

Comment: Because this is a abstraction of a real use case, and it is the simplest markup I could find to show the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use Outer div which contains two spans (span because it is inline).
Give position of one span as float left and other as float right .
I have tested it multiple times with the chrome and safari , you can try that also . Let me know if it works for you .

```
.foo {
    float:left;
}

.bar {
    float: right;
}

#headerDiv{
     width:100%;
     height:20px;
}

<div id="headerDiv">
 <span class='foo'>Foo</span>
    <span class='bar'>Bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I am sorry, it seems I wasn't clear enought but I don't want a way of aligning the two elements. The markup you see here actualy works as well for aligning two elements. it works in every browser, even Chrome, but sometimes it doesn't and this is all my question is about

Comment: These are called as race condition which is difficult to debug , this can also happen because of DOM loading again and again .